# New column based on string value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, union

I'm running SSMS17.
I have a `varchar(50)` column named 'Type' and an ID(`smallint`) in my query that has these values in it

| Type | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Paper HD | 1 |
| Paper | 3 |
| Wood HD | 2 |
| Sheet | 4 |
| Cup HD | 6 |
| ETC.. | 7 |

These values are always assigned to my query results.
I want to create a new column that search's this Type column and if the string has HD, cast 'Finished' and the ID value in a new column, and if theres no HD in the string put 'Ready'

I know I can do this in two separate queries doing

```
select
'Finished_'+cast(ID as varchar) AS 'TypeID'
..from... where Type like ('%HD%') ,
```

and

```
select
'_'+cast(ID as varchar) AS 'TypeID'
..from... where Type NOT like ('%HD%') ,
```

and then union them

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: *im running SSMS17* then you are long overdue updating it.

Comment: Ssms is only your client ui - what does `select @@version` return?

Comment: @DaleK it returns Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64)

Comment: Anyway look into a `case` expression

Comment: 2014 - that's even worse! Time to upgrade.

Comment: haha yes probably, company policy unfortunately so nothing i can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case expression:

```
select
  case when Type like '%HD%' then 'Finished_' else '' end 
  + cast(ID as varchar(10)) as TypeID
```

You can also simplify using `concat` (I think this was available back in 2014)

```
select concat(case when Type like '%HD%' then 'Finished_' end, ID) as TypeID
```

Note, always specify a size for `varchar()`, column aliases shoud not be 'quoted' but [delimited] - but only if necessary.